# How can I stop an Apollo GraphQL query with required exported variables from fetching when those variables are removed

Tags: graphql, single-page-application, apollo-client

### The Problem

When navigating away from query components that use the state of the app route as required variables, I get GraphQL errors of the sort:

> Variable "$analysisId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.

"Navigating away" means, for example, going

- from: `/analysis/analysis-1/analyse/`
- to: `/user-profile/`

### Background

I am building an SPA using Apollo GraphQL, and I have some queries which follow this pattern:

```gql
query Analyse($analysisId: ID!) {
  location @client {
    params {
      analysisId @export(as: "analysisId")
    }
  }

  analysis(analysisId: $analysisId) {
    id
    # ... etc
  }
}
```

The `location` field gets a representation of the SPA router's state. That state is held in an Apollo client "reactive variable". Query components are programmed to not begin subscribing to the query unless that reactive variable exists and has the required content.

```js
shouldSubscribe(): boolean {
  return !!(locationVar()?.params?.analysisId);
}
```

Params represents express-style URL params, so the route path is `/analysis/:analysisId/analyse`.

If the user navigates to `/analysis/analysis-1/analyse`, the query component's `variables` become: { analysisId: "analysis-1" }`. This works fine when loading the component.

### What I Think is Happening

When the component connects to the DOM, it checks to see if it's required variables are present in the router state, and if they are, it creates an `ObservableQuery` and subscribes.

Later, when the user navigates away, the `ObservableQuery` is still subscribed to updates when suddenly the required `analysisId` variable, exported by the client field `location.params.analysisId` is nullified.

I think that since the `ObservableQuery` is still subscribed, it sends off the query with null `analysisId` variable, even though it's required.

### What I've Tried

By breaking on every method in my [query component base class](https://apolloelements.dev/classes/_apollo_elements_interfaces.apolloqueryinterface.html), I'm reasonably sure that the component base class is not at fault - there's no evidence that it is refetching the component when the route changes. Instead, I think this is happening inside the apollo client.

I could perhaps change the schema for the query from `analysis(analysisId: ID!): Analysis` to `analysis(analysisId: ID): Analysis`, but that seems roundabout, as I might not have control over the server.

How do I prevent apollo client from trying to fetch a query when it has required variables and they are not present?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine so far, in my HttpLink, `src/apollo/link/http.ts`:

```ts
import { ApolloLink, from } from '@apollo/client/link/core';
import { HttpLink } from '@apollo/client/link/http';
import { hasAllVariables } from '@apollo-elements/lib/has-all-variables';

const uri =
  'GRAPHQL_HOST/graphql';

export const httpLink = from([
  new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    if (!hasAllVariables(operation))
      return;
    else
      return forward(operation);
  }),
  new HttpLink({ uri }),
]);
```